# asp.net core web api does not accept extra headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ocelot

I have a Web API Gateway which calls other micro services. The communication between Gateway and micro services works fine.

I am not able to use "AddClaimsToRequest" but am able to use "UpstreamHeaderTransform" .

Does OCelot 16.xx supports AddClaimsToRequest ? It gives me 403 error.

And also the values in global config are ignored.

```
"GlobalConfiguration": {
    "AddHeadersToRequest": {
      "ahtr": "anything"
    },
    "UpstreamHeaderTransform": {
      "ush": "anything"
    },
    "DownstreamHeaderTransform": {
      "dsh": "anything"
    },
    "AddClaimsToRequest": {
      "acr": "anything"
    },
    "RouteClaimsRequirement": {
      "rcr": "anything"
    }
  },
```